# Kendo datepicker sending 1 day due to JSON.stringify()

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo Grid with datapicker fields in it. When i save the record it is sending one day less to the controller.

What may be the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/BCBzS/17/

I am using the same example

```
<!-- grid element -->
<div id="grid" style="width: 700px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>

var data = createRandomData(50);
var autoCompleteDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        {firstName: "Alex"},
        {firstName: "Alice"},
        {firstName: "Antony"},
        {firstName: "Anne"},
        {firstName: "Anna"}
    ]
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: data,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        FirstName: { type: "string" },
                        LastName: { type: "string" },
                        City: { type: "string" },
                        Title: { type: "string" },
                        BirthDate: { type: "date" },
                        Age: { type: "number" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 10
        },
        height: 450,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        editable: {
            mode: "popup",
            template: $("#popup_editor").html()
        },
        edit: function(e) {
            $(e.container)
                .find("input[name='FirstName']")
                    .data("kendoAutoComplete")
                        .bind("change", function(e) {
                            console.log("auto complete changed");
                        });
        },
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [
            {
                field: "FirstName",
                title: "First Name",
                width: 100
            },
            {
                field: "BirthDate",
                title: "Birth Date",
                template: '#= kendo.toString(BirthDate,"MM/dd/yyyy") #'
            },
            {
                field: "Age",
                width: 100
            },
            {
                command: ["edit", "destroy"],
                title: "&nbsp;",
                width: "200px"
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Actually i selected date 10/07/2014 But when it sends data it is like 2014-07-09T18:30:00.000Z

This is because of JSON.stringify();

Comment: do like to play guessing game? :D please use the keyboard and type some codes... ;)

Comment: @Reigel http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/BCBzS/17/

I am doing the same example using Kendo jsp wrapper and Spring Controller. When i save the form date one day less it is going

Comment: Most likely because JSON stringify converts to UTC. Just revert it on the controller to local, or account for the utc conversion on client side before sending.

Comment: @gitsitgo Before sending data to controller the date is exact what i selected but when sending data it is like return JSON.stringify(data).
this is causing problem